# How do I extract only the first element from a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, object

I have a menu with two submenus that animate by sliding open when the user clicks on the appropriate menu heading. That function is provided by this code:

```
$('ul#main_menu > li:has( ul.sub-menu )').click(function()
    {
        var $sublist = jQuery(this).find('ul:first');
        $sublist.slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
```

Now, I want to make the first submenu open when the user clicks on a span that I've set up (it has an `id` of `open_artists`. I've been trying to modify the above code to accomplish that. This works, but opens both submenus. I only want to open the first submenu.

```
function openArtists () {

        var $sublist = jQuery('ul#main_menu > li:has( ul.sub-menu )').find('ul:first');
        $sublist.slideToggle('fast');

        return false;

}

$('#open_artists').click(openArtists);
```

I've tried to modify it to:

```
function openArtists () {

        var $sublist = jQuery('ul#main_menu > li:has( ul.sub-menu )').find('ul:first');
        var $firstsublist = jQuery('$sublist').first();
        $firstsublist.slideToggle('fast');

        return false;

}

$('#open_artists').click(openArtists);
```

But this isn't working. Nor has anything else I've tried.

Comment: Can you please add your html mockup too? Also try `.eq(0)` in place of `.first()`. Not sure if it'll work till we see your HTML.

Comment: To answer this, we'd need to see your relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select first **ul** then find the **sublist**

```
function openArtists () {

        var $sublist = jQuery('ul#main_menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').find('ul').eq(0);
        $sublist.slideToggle('fast');

        return false;

}
```